# Add Variable To All Routes

Tags: laravel, url

I need to display a variable (taken from user model) to all routes in my application which has no impact on the route it's being displayed on. So home/variable will display the same home page regardless of that variable to all users. If the user just goes to myapp/home the variable would append itself to the url as myapp/home/variable.

I already have my desired outcome with the below in web.php, but I have to do this with every route, so if my app has two pages I do the same redirect for both /home and /example. It also means I have to add the variable whenever I redirect from another controller.

```
Route::get( '/example',function(){   
    $var  = Auth::user()->thevariable;
    return redirect('example/'.$var);
}); 
Route::get( 'example/{var}','ExampleController@index');

// changes the url from example, to example/variable, and also returns
the correct controller / view if directed to example/variable.
```

In my controllers I do something like this to redirect if needed:

```
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index',$user->thevariable)
//I can also just redirect to the /home url and the variable is added 
automatically, but this messes up passing session data.
```

Can it be done better with a composer, middleware or even through the RouteServiceProvider? If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated (laravel 5.4).

Comment: So there is for example the site `/settings` and `/settings/{id}`? What is the use case?

Comment: So the page `/settings` is the same as `/settings/{id}` , if the user types /settings into their url `{thevariable}` will automatically be appended, so regardless of which page they visit or how the get there the url will always read something like: `/any/path/{constantvariable}`

Comment: Add variable to all routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#default-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge so far: If you want to use different paths you need to write down every path in the Routing. But the decision which one is choosen, will be done by a middleware. So you create your own middleware and attach here to all those paths with `->middleware('myOwnMW');`. It should like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class myOwnMW
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->thevariable) {
        //redirect to your path
        $uri = $request->path() . '/'. $variableIwantToAttach;
        return redirect($uri);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Hope you get the idea. Check here for [path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#request-path-and-method). Dont forget to register your middleware inside the `Kernel.php` and here is a [tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-57-middleware-tutorial-with-exampleexample.html) i used a while ago.

Comment: Thanks so much I will give this a try shortly!

Comment: just a question in relation to the if statement, why are we checking the session for a key? If I'm grabbing my variable from `auth::user` for example I should check for this or is there another reason I'm missing?

Comment: No you aint missing anything :D I just didnt know what you are checking.  You can take the variable from auth::user, thats just fine. Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to be sure, this is now displaying the url as intended! Although I still need to figure out my routes as `Route::get ( 'test/{tester}','Controller@test');` displays url: `myapp/test/var/var` and if I take out the curly brackets it goes to `myapp/test/var` but takes this as the route and so won't find that page..